# How do I write a conditional CustomLog statement for my Apache 2.4 VirtualHost?

Tags: logging, configuration, virtualhost, apache2.4

I'm using the following version of Apache (2.4) ...

```
$ sudo apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 24 2019 13:45:48
```

I want to write custom log directives in my virtual host block such that host headers taht match my domain go to one log and all others go to a different log ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com

    # Use the Host header to determine where to log
    # Use the Host header to determine how to respond. 
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" expr="%{HTTP_HOST} == 'mydomain.com'"
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/garbage_access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" expr="%{HTTP_HOST} != 'mydomain.com'"

    Alias /static /var/www/html/frontpage/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/frontpage/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Next, add the following directory block
    <Directory /var/www/html/frontpage>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess frontpage python-home=/var/www/html/venv python-path=/var/www/html
    WSGIProcessGroup frontpage
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/frontpage_project/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the above is producing this error

```
$ sudo apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mydomain.conf:
CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause (see docs)
```

How do I set up the custom log statements properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the whole expression should be quoted, together with the "expr=", i.e:

```
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" "expr=%{HTTP_HOST} == 'mydomain.com'"
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/garbage_access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" "expr=%{HTTP_HOST} != 'mydomain.com'"
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples, the last example

Comment: Winner!  I have to wait at least 24 hours to award the bounty so I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: To save checking the expression twice and to make it easier to modify later, consider setting an environment variable (e.g., SetEnvIfExpr "tolower(%{HTTP_HOST}) == 'mydomain.com'" IsMyDomain) and then use "env=IsMyDomain" with CustomLog